# REST API Cannot get

Tags: api, rest, insomnia

Hi Im starting to learn how apis works and got my first stucktrace.
The thing is that Im trying this code

```
const app = require('express')();

const PORT = 8080;


app.get('/tshirt', (req , res) => {
    res.status(200).send({
        tshirt: 'blue',
        size: 'large'
    })
});
```

But Insomnia show me "Cannot GET /tshirt" and 404 at 'http://localhost:8080/tshirt'

So my question is why this doesnt work?

Additional information:
On firefox I cant run 'http://localhost:8080/tshirt' instead I have to run 'localhost:8080/tshirt'.
But on Insomnia I cant test 'localhost:8080/tshirt' and have to run 'http://localhost:8080/tshirt'.

Comment: I tried your code and accessing `http://localhost:8080/tshirt` does work on Firefox. If you access the link starts with `http://` on Firefox, what error do you get?

Comment: Yes firefox isn't the problem, insomnia is, I will try postman instead and see whats happening.

Comment: I dont know how but now is fixed.. haha *screams of agony*

Comment: the project was not initialized with the node . command...  thats the thing.. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

1.As far as I know, using Promises, it's will your help. please try this.

```
const getTshirt = async (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send({
        tshirt: 'blue',
        size: 'large'
    })
};
```

```
app.get('/tshirt', getTshirt);
```

Comment: Good practice but dont solve my problem, anyway I will implement it in future productions

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).